# LUIS: Identify "normalized" value based on synonyms automatically

Tags: nlp, azure-language-understanding

I am currently developing a chatbot that recommends theater plays to the user.

It is working pretty well, but now I want to enable the user to get recommendations based on the type of theater plays (like funny, dramatic, sad).
Nevertheless, as I do not know how exactly the user is phrasing the request also synonyms might be used (funny: witty, humourous, ...)

What is a good solution to get these types from the user's request in a normalized way?

Typically I would use the List entity, but then I have to insert all synonyms for each possible value by myself. Is there a way how i can define my "normalized" values and synonyms are automatically matched by LUIS (and improved by further training of the model)

Comment: I tried to do this with phrase lists but it doesn't seem to work. The values, though marked as interchangeable, don't seem to trigger the entity recognition. This site mentions using phrase lists when LUIS needs to learn new alternatives often, but as I mentioned, I can't seem to get it to work. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-tutorial-list-entity

Comment: I might be misunderstanding the ask, but can you create an entity (for example `emotionalattribute`) and then just put in a decent amount of training utterances to train it properly? Or are you are concerned with capturing those utterances (those synonyms that they actually use), to be able to see what users are actually using?

Also, not quite what it's meant for, but you can always look into [Sentiment Analysis](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-reference-prebuilt-sentiment?tabs=english).

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55643327/how-to-get-normalized-value-for-list-type-entity-from-microsoft-bot-builder-reco) too