# How to get all Normalized values for a LUIS list entity?

Tags: azure-language-understanding

I have a List entity named 'ChatBot'. Its Normalized values are the following

[image]

If my input text has keyword VA, then LUIS result will return 'ChatBot' entity. I want to get all other normalized values for this entity. For the above example if VA is there in the input, then I need 'qna bot', 'chat bot', 'Virtual Assistant' in my result. Is there anyway I can get all of its list values from a list entity ?

Comment: List entities by design return the normalized value of the list check the reference doc https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/reference-entity-list?tabs=V2 You can achieved your desired behavior by post processing the LUIS reponse

Comment: @MagedRefaat When I input 'qna bot'. I'm getting the Enitity Key as 'ChatBot' and Entity Value as ['qna bot']. I'm using LUIS SDK. My requirement is to get all values for the entity like ['qna bot','va','chat bot', 'Virtual Assistant']

Comment: May I ask what your use case is? There may be other ways to accomplish what you want if we can understand what you need the list for.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get normalized value for List type Entity from Microsoft.Bot.Builder.RecognizerResult?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55643327/how-to-get-normalized-value-for-list-type-entity-from-microsoft-bot-builder-reco)

Comment: @billoverton It is for a search use case, where if user search for chat bot then search should have documents related to chatbot, qna bot, virtual assistant, VA etc.. I'm just checking the possibility of whether I can use LUIS in this use case.